# Anaconda Navigator: Is there a way to view the console?

Tags: anaconda

When I launch things from the Anaconda Navigator, I want to see what it's doing so I can do the same thing from a shell or command prompt. Is there a way to do this? Sorry if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: What are you using from Anaconda Navigator? If it is just Python, then there are existing shell and command prompt options available.

Comment: Thanks @astrochun!! I'm using Spyder. I want to make a shortcut to launch Spyder without using Navigator, but my attempts have failed so far. The included Spyder shortcuts now point to an outdated version of Spyder. I tried modifying the included Spyder shortcut to point to a different version of Spyder-Script.py, but that didn't work. I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: There are a number of IDEs available that is compatible with conda packaging. I use PyCharm and it has many things that help programmers code faster. I've only used Spyder briefly (one of my students use it). See below for possible answer/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this documentation page: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/

On my terminal I was able to launch with a single one-word command:
`(base) laptop user$ spyder3`

If you are on Windows, you will want to open Anaconda Prompt first.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite understand how to appropriately modify your command to fit my needs, but you inspired me to do something similar. Would this make sense? 1. Open the shell that comes with Microsoft Git. 2. enter "spyder" from my base environment.

Comment: Do you not have Anaconda Prompt? It should be included in your install. I'm not sure if the Microsoft git is aware of `conda`

Comment: Cool, thanks! I do have Anaconda Prompt, I'm just trying to make a shortcut so that I can open Spyder with one click. Is there a way to automate that process?

Comment: I think I got Microsoft Git to recognize conda by making it start in my base environment. Does that make sense? I made a shell script whose contents are just "spyder" and that's working for me as a shortcut.

Comment: Also, I will upvote this answer once I have enough rep.